# Suggestions of structure terraform template and folders

Tags: terraform

We are looking to have the ability to create VM (and related resources) in various different cloud providers.

So we will end up with different template for different cloud providers.
Current structure

```
|_terraform
    |_azure
    |     |_vm
    |        |_module
    |        |_testazurevm1
    |        |    |_.terraform
    |        |         |_plugins
    |        |         |_modules
    |        |_testazurevm2
    |        |    |_.terraform
    |        |         |_plugins
    |        |         |_modules
    |        |_...
    |            |_.terraform
    |                 |_plugins
    |                 |_modules
    |___aws
    |     |_vm
    |        |_module
    |        |_testawsvm1
    |        |    |_.terraform
    |        |         |_plugins
    |        |         |_modules
    |        |_testawsvm2
    |        |    |_.terraform
    |        |         |_plugins
    |        |         |_modules
    |        |_...
    |            |_.terraform
    |                 |_plugins
    |                 |_modules
    |____....
```

It kind of works, but each time when we perform terraform init/apply in one of the subfolders, it always create a new .terraform subfolder which contains the binary executable of the providers and reference link to modules.

When we are going to have hundreds / thousands of VMs, we'll have these executable in each VM/.terraform/plugins folder.

Is there a way to tell terraform to reuse the existing plugins in designated folder?

Comment: do you not have a separate terraform project that re-uses these modules?

Comment: I'm using the open source edition terraform, and I'm really a beginner. Can you please define terraform project?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I've found terraform init have -plugin-dir switch, which allows us to specify a folder, where the plugins can be predownloaded.

So we don't have to check-in the executable plugin binaries into source control.

This is mentioned in:
https://www.terraform.io/guides/running-terraform-in-automation.html

```
terraform init -input=false -plugin-dir=/usr/lib/custom-terraform-plugins
```

When this option is used, only the plugins in the given directory are available for use. This gives the system administrator a high level of control over the execution environment, but on the other hand it prevents use of newer plugin versions that have not yet been installed into the local plugin directory. Which approach is more appropriate will depend on unique constraints within each organization.